# Instantiation of a PHP class without assignment to a variable

Tags: php, codeigniter

I came a cross this line of code in Codeigniter HMVC extension (by Wiredesignz), where a class got instantiated without getting assigned to a variable (class CI in Base.php)

The code :

```
class CI extends CI_Controller
{
  public static $APP;

  public function __construct() {

    /* assign the application instance */
    self::$APP = $this;

    global $LANG, $CFG;

    /* re-assign language and config for modules */
    if ( ! is_a($LANG, 'MX_Lang')) $LANG = new MX_Lang;
    if ( ! is_a($CFG, 'MX_Config')) $CFG = new MX_Config;

    parent::__construct();
  }
}

/* create the application object */
new CI;
```

What's the name of this technique?
What's the implication?

Comment: If this is the CodeIgniter I just lost interest learning it or even having anything in common with it.

Comment: @shadyyx read the first line of the question.

Comment: @Vlakarados that it is an extension, so not real CI? But I suppose CI still uses `global`s then...

Comment: @shadyyx not an official extension. Anyway, I agree that in this current case it's bad.

Comment: @Vlakarados IMHO, in modern OO programming and (H)MV[C|P] architecture there is no place for `global`s.

Comment: @shadyyx sorry, I've edited my comment above, I agree about that. But please, remember one thing - don't blame framework or programming language for bad user code :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has not a name and the implication is, that the constructor is definitely doing too much. The reason one wants to create an instance of a class without referencing it is, that he only wants the constructor wants to be executed, but nothing more. This means, that the constructor "does" something, but a constructor should only ensure, that an object is in a stable/valid state and nothing more.

In short: Don't assume that this is a good practice. The `global` and `self::$APP = $this` confirms my opinion that this is a bad piece of code.

Comment: Sorry, but did you really mean to place that comma in the last sentence? :)

Comment: I do agree, very bad piece of code, indeed. And very bad practice, too.

Comment: Ah, now I get it, Thanks. Not a native speaker and punctuation ... not even in my language :D

Comment: @KingCrunch it happens :) Amuses me everytime, a small `,` that completely reverses the point of the sentence :)

Comment: @KingCrunch - I didn't assume it like that, just curious how that can work ie. the object can be referenced without it having a reference (variable). Already removed the extension, hard to navigate and debug. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this could be seen as some sort of `facade design`.
-The Class(constructor is called) and assignment is done, albeit in the constructor itself.

so `new CI` is just extending the Super object and initializing its own constructor. 
Similar to a function,  `function somefun(){ return }; somefunc();//call somefunc`

**CI_Controller** loads all of the classes required to run Codeigniter, it is the **SUPER object**

```
$ci = &get_instance() // CI_Controller
```

Comment: The thing that baffled me is the instantiation of CI without assigning it to a variable... 

There's already a $CI declared in index.php of type CI_Controller.
Now a CI of type CI.

Both CI and $CI are objects, the latter is a variable but what about the former?

How is it managed by PHP?

At first I thought maybe it's meant to be singleton, but at any other place anyone can declare another object of type CI though this time he might have to assign it to a variable. 

Dropped the extension though... using one from Jens Segers.